# Deploy only one function to Function Apps

Tags: azure

I have a function app in azure which has many functions. 
And, I have a solution which has 6-7 azure function projects, now, I would like to deploy only one function to azure portal. While deploying only one function to azure portal, other functions are getting deleted. Please suggest some way to deploy only one function to portal instead of all the functions.

Function app in portal:
Function1
Function2
Function3
Function4

Visual studio solution
Project 1: Function1, Function2
Project 2: Function3
Project 3: Function4

There is change in Function3, when I deploy Function3, existing Function1, Function2 & Function3 are deleted.

Kindly suggest sole solution to deploy only Function3 without deleting Function1 & Function2 & Function4

Answer (score 0):

You can’t really do what you want. You deploy the whole function project, so it’s going to overwrite what is there. To achieve what you want you’d need to split your functions into different projects, or always deploy all functions ( which shouldn’t really be an issue if you’ve not made any changes).